Theorem 4.10, Kunen, VI.
In Kunens "Set Theory An Introduction to Independence Proofs", we are given the following (thm 4.10, chap. IV):

Let $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n$ be any axioms of $\sf{ZF} + \mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L}$; then $$\exists M \left(|M| = \omega \land M \ \text{is transitive} \land \bigwedge\limits_{i = 1}^{n} \phi^M_i\right). \qquad \qquad (*)$$

The proof Kunen gives is the following:

The fact that $(*)$ follows from $\sf{ZF}+\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L}$ is a direct application of IV 7.11. Thus, working in $\sf{ZF}$, we know that $(*)$ holds relativized to $\mathbf{L}$. We now check, by absoluteness that $M$ satisfies $(*)$ in $\mathbf{V}$. $(|M| = \omega)^{\mathbf{L}}$, so there is an $f \in {\mathbf{L}}$ such that $(f \ \text{maps $\omega$ $1$-$1$ onto $M$})^{\mathbf{L}}$. Then, $f$ maps $\omega$ $1$-$1$ onto $M$, so that $|M| = \omega$. $(\text{$M$ is transitive})^{\mathbf{L}}$ implies $M$ is transitive. Finally, since ${\mathbf{L}}$ is transitive, each $(\phi_i^M)^{\mathbf{L}}$ is equivalent to $\phi_i^M$, so $M$ satisfies $(*)$ in $\mathbf{V}$.

I feel like I don't understand the structure of this proof.

Am I correct that $\sf{ZF}+\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L}$ is an extension of $\sf{ZFC}$ since $\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L} \rightarrow \text{AC}$, so that we can apply theorem 7.11 (chapter V, Kunen):


Let $S$ be any set of axioms extending $\sf{ZFC}$ and $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n$ any axioms of $S$; then $$S \vdash \exists M\left(|M| = \omega \land \text{$M$ is transitive} \land \bigwedge\limits_{i = 1}^{n}\phi_i^M \right). \qquad \qquad (**)$$


Is it correct that this means that from $(**)$ applied to $\sf{ZF}+\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L}$ we get that $$\sf{ZF}+\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L} \vdash \exists M\left(|M| = \omega \land \text{$M$ is transitive} \land \bigwedge\limits_{i = 1}^{n}\phi_i^M \right). \qquad \qquad (***)$$ But this is internally to $\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L}$, which means that the RHS of $(***)$ is really saying

\begin{align*}
 &\left(\exists M\left(|M| = \omega \land \text{$M$ is transitive} \land
 \bigwedge\limits_{i = 1}^{n}\phi_i^M \right)\right)^{\mathbf{L}}\\
=
&\exists M \in \mathbf{L}\left((|M| = \omega)^{\mathbf{L}} \land
(\text{$M$ is transitive})^{\mathbf{L}} \land \bigwedge\limits_{i =
1}^{n} (\phi_i^{M})^{\mathbf{L}}\right) \qquad \qquad (****)
\end{align*}
If the above is correct, we then check that the subformulas inside $(****)$ relativized to $\mathbf{L}$ are the same as in $\mathbf{V}$ (externally)? I am somewhat confused, since I naively think that due to the fact that $\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L}$, one should not have to check this individually.

Does it follow that $$(\phi_i^M)^{\mathbf{L}} = \phi_i^{M \cap \mathbf{L}} \qquad (-)$$ since $M \in \mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{L}$ is transitive, this becomes $M$? I am not sure I have seen Kunen do a relativization of an already relativized formula (as in $(-)$) so this threw me off a little.


$\vdash$ is \vdash not \dashv. I think all your points are correct, but we are not assuming $V=L$, so why do you think "one should not have to check this individually"? You are right that $(\phi^M)^L$ is the same as $\phi^{M\cap L}$, but $M=M\cap L$ because $M\in L$ and $L$ is transitive, so $(\phi^M)^L$ is equivalent to $\phi^M$

Yes, you are ofc right, it should be $\vdash$, fixed =). Reg. last point, yes! That is what I meant by "this becomes $M$". Sorry, I should have been clearer.

@newaccount I am unsure about why $\left(\phi_i^M\right)^{\mathbf{L}} = (\phi_{i})^{M \cap \mathbf{L}}$ holds though, since this is not generally the case.

It holds as long as $M\in L$, which implies $M=M\cap L$
